# How can I put data from UITextField to IBAction string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have **UITextField** named **textField** where user can save phone number with **NSUserDefaults**. Then I have **IBAction** to call that number. How can I put to that action a number what user have been saved to **UITextField**?

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456"]];
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (IBAction) saveBtnPresssed : (id) sender
{
    myString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:textField.text];
    [textField setText:myString1];
    NSUserDefaults *stringDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [stringDefault setObject:myString1 forKey:@"stringKey"];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [textField setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey"]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you are looking for is returned by:

```
[textField text];
```

If you saved that to user defaults then you can just:

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *phoneNumberString = [defaults objectForKey:@"key_you_saved_the_number_with"];

//... do what you need with that number here
```

}

EDIT:

```
    [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@"], [defaults objectForKey:@"stringKey"]];
```

so the resulting string should be "tel:" + the actual number from the text field instead of "tel:123456"

Comment: I updated my question, can you tell me how can I put the number to URLWithString:@"tel:123456"

Comment: Why it gives me an error: use of undeclared identifier "defaults"?

Comment: That worked for me: -(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *telURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"stringKey"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telURL]];
}

Answer (score 0):

In your code setting the textfiled with the same string is not required.
Simply use:

```
 (IBAction) saveBtnPresssed : (id) sender
{
    myString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:textField.text];
    NSUserDefaults *stringDefault = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myString1 forKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];
}
```

This would set the string to your defaults and you can fetch the data as

```
NSString *pString = [defaults objectForKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];
```